# WPF find a nested menuitem in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, find

I have an image that has a nested context menu defined in the XAML (shown below).

I am trying to use a for loop to find a menu and uncheck it using IsChecked=false.

my code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            MenuItem theMenu = (MenuItem)this.FindName("beat" + i.ToString());
            theMenu.IsChecked = false;
        }
```

the above does not work and returns a null.

what am I doing wrong!

excerpt from the XAML

```
<Image x:Name="Options" Height="35" Source="Images/pad-options-button.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="47" Canvas.Left="740" Canvas.Top="293"
           MouseUp="Options_MouseUp">
        <Image.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Beats">
            <MenuItem Name="beat1" Header="1" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat2" Header="2" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat3" Header="3" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat4" Header="4" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat5" Header="5" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat6" Header="6" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat7" Header="7" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat8" Header="8" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat9" Header="9" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat10" Header="10" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat11" Header="11" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat12" Header="12" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat13" Header="13" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat14" Header="14" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat15" Header="15" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="beat16" Header="16" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Beat Type">
            <MenuItem Name="Whole" Header="Whole" Click="MenuBeatType_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name ="Half" Header="Half" Click="MenuBeatType_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name ="Quarter" Header="Quarter" Click="MenuBeatType_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name ="Eighth" Header="Eighth" Click="MenuBeatType_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name ="Sixteenth" Header="Sixteenth" Click="MenuBeatType_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</Image.ContextMenu>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Where do you execute the for loop and what is `this` there?

Comment: it executes in a function on the code side of a usercontrol.  when i debug "this" is the usercontrol itself.  worth noting the image in question is inside a canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other option is to get the context menu from the image.

```
var items = Options.ContextMenu.Items
foreach(MenuItem item in items)
{ 
    // do your work with the item 
}
```

Be arware that you will have to handle the sub items!
Items will have only 2 items in your case

Comment: how do I reference the submenu from the parent?  sorry, used to working in winforms where children collections are present

Comment: As explained above... Options is the name of your image so this should work. What you maybe have to do is to cast the ".ContextMenu" to ContextMenu bevore you can access the items property

Comment: slightly changed the XAML to explicitly name a few more items and then used the below

private void MenuBeats_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            foreach(MenuItem item in MenuBeats.Items)
            {
                item.IsChecked = false;
            }

            MenuItem theSelectedMenu = (MenuItem)sender;
            theSelectedMenu.IsChecked = true;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect markup. Last two symbols shouldn't be there:

```
<MenuItem Name="beat8" Header="8" Click="MenuBeats_Click"/>/>
```

However, you example perfectly works for me, but with accidental item:

> "/>"

Comment: sorry, thats a paste error, I removed the erroneous closing tag and the theMenu variable still returns null

Answer (score 0):

Just in the constructor of the class in code behind write `NameScope.SetNameScope(contextMenu, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));` contextMenu is the name given to context menu of image. Actually ContextMenu is not the part of Visual tree so it cant find the names . but the above line of code will set context menu in the scope of visual tree and hence will find the names. Hope this will help.

Comment: hi, I added that line of code and get a runtime error, value parameter cannot be null (ContextMenu) .  I take it that ContextMenu is the type and not supposed to be the name of the menu in the XAML

Comment: contextMenu is the name of your xaml context menu like x:Name="contextMenu" not the type ContextMenu.

Comment: `contextMenu` should be you ContextMenu name and start with lower case, so shouldn't give any error. Correct case of the fist letter.

Comment: 'NameScope.SetNameScope(nameofyourcontextmenu, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));    <Image.ContextMenu>     <ContextMenu x:Name="nameofyourcontextmenu">

Comment: hi, i added NameScope.SetNameScope(MenuBeats, NameScope.GetNameScope(this)); to the constructor and it makes no difference the theMenu variable is still null

Comment: make sure that it is written after InitializeComponent() method